# Docker GUI Font Problems

Tags: docker, gnuradio-companion

I am currently having issues with the font display when running GNURADIO Companion from a docker environment.  I can get the GUI to show, but the font characters are displayed as wingdings, which I am unable to read.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thank you

Mark

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: This is a completely false statement.  I actually found a hint USING Stackoverflow, because someone else posted a similar problem, with all the fonts they wanted were not available.  I deduced the problems were similar, and figured out the issues.  I posted this problem and answer to help anyone else who may have this problem.  So back off.

Comment: No, I won't back off giving feedback. This is a programming q&a site based on giving feedback, so please stay polite. The close reason I posted does indeed not perfectly fit your problem, but I really think that "I thought I've installed xyz but it turns out I didn't" is in the same category as "I mistyped".

Comment: Thanks and have a wonderful day!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

*Update*

I figured out that the base image simply didn't have the fonts installed, as I thought it did.  I performed the actions below and now have a readable GNURADIO Companion.

yum install python-matplotlib
fc-cache

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the key is to install proper fonts. And, if/when you are using Debian, the fonts list can be found [here](https://packages.debian.org/stable/fonts/).

```
apt install fonts-YOUR-CHOSEN-FONT-NAME
```